# How do I type っ on an iPhone kana keyboard?

Tags: discussion

You can press the た key 6 times consecutively to write っ on an iPhone kana keyboard, but that seems inconvenient. Is there a faster way to write っ?

Answer (score 1):

Swipe up on the た key to write つ, then press the ["。小] key. The つ will be transformed into っ.